# How does symfony auto convert foreign keys to entities?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms, php-8

I am just getting started in PHP Symfony with an existing project. The project is deployed and it works but locally on different environments there's something strange for some endpoints which involve a list of foreign keys (Many to Many) which I can't figure out.
So I have an Entity Person who can own multiple Houses (Many to Many) and has a main house. When creating a person, houses as foreign keys are passed together with person like this:

```
  {
   "name": "John Doe",
   "mainHouse": 62,
   "houses": [62]
  }
```

In the corrected version, the JSON object consists of three key-value pairs: "name" with the value "John Doe", "mainHouse" with the value 62, and "houses" with an array containing the number 62.

In Person Entity everything seems well defined:

```
class Person
{ 
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=House::class, inversedBy="owners")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="person_house")
     */
    private $houses;

 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=House::class)
     */
    private $mainHouse;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

And the type class for form definition:

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
  .
  .
  ->add('houses', EntityType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'class' => House::class
            ])
  ->add('mainHouse', EntityType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'class' => House::class
            ])
  .
  .
}
```

The controller for creating a Person looks like this:

```
public function createPerson(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $person = new Person();
        $content = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $form = $this->createForm(PersonType::class, $person);
        $form->submit($content);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($person);
            $em->flush();

            return $person;
        }

        return $form;
```

My problem is everytime I pass foreign keys for a list of houses even if they exist in the database I get a bad request (Validation failed) on line $form->isValid() with  "this value is not valid" for the attribute houses but not for mainHouse. And this happens for all other attributes of type list which take a list of foreign keys.
In general I haven't figured out how symfony finds these foreign keys in the request body and converts them to entity, and why would simple values work not a list. Searched around ParamConverters and DataTransformers but I haven't seen anything related to that in my project.And I am even more confused to see this works in production but not locally. Is there something extra I am required to do to activate this feature?

Comment: how are you sending that json (the example isn't json, but has numerous typos btw)? besides that, I don't see anything wrong and would resort to a blanket `bin/console cache:clear` in the hopes that some weird component is caching something old ....

Comment: I am sending the JSON from a REST client. You're right, I missed the commas in my question, but my actual JSON is okay and as I mentioned it works for endpoints which do not involve a list of foreign keys. I am on Docker, so little or no chances of caching, I recreate the whole environment on every deploy. Do you know though how these foreign keys are mapped?

Comment: @Berchmans Why do you use symfony form if you consume the data via JSON/RESTFul?

Comment: do you have a web frontend where maybe the last requests can be seen in the profiler? in there, you can see, what actually ends up at the form interface. (@HansFooBar to get the validation and property/entity population that come with forms.)

Comment: @Jakumi It appears to be a JSON payload and not a request from a form. Therefore my question. If it is a JSON payload, it is not implemented correctly. But I would like to know that before showing how it could be correct.

Comment: @Hans it is actually a project in production that I have just been given to fix something. I can't question much what has been done before but since it works in production I think it's something I have missed in probably config or something else. I agree with you yes, there was no need for forms, but I suppose the dev started from PHP easy my admin and extended it to have endpoints accepting and returning JSON.

Comment: @Jakumi The request body ends well inside the endpoint with correct values, somehow I have excluded the possibility that correct data is received by the endpoint (I can well see the values before form submit). It's more at some point during form submit Symfony/Doctrine picks the foreign keys and replaces them by entities, and that's the part that has something wrong but only for attributes of type array/list. And the mechanism behind is exactly what I don't understand.

Comment: @Jakumi actually if I link my frontend with the backend which is deployed on staging I don't have the issue, meaning the problem is more the config of my local backend. I was hoping there's an action I can do in configs may be to activate this mapping.

Comment: another point might be a different database, do the entities with those keys actually exist in your local database?

Comment: @john they do exist in the database yes. For foreign keys which are not list there is not problem. Only problem is in Many To Many r/ship

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downgrading PHP version. I had PHP v8.2.5, downgraded to PHP v8.0.29. I didn't see the composer install packages incompatibility error message by just running composer install until I used PhpStorm prompt for composer install which indicated that some packages were not compatible with my PHP version hence the downgrade.